# Copy argv into new array

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, argv

I'm getting a segmentation fault for the following code.  Can somebody explain why?  I would like to be able to copy the contents of argv into a new array, which I called rArray.

```
#include <iostream>        
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
  char **rArray;
  int numRows = argc;
  cout << "You have " << argc << " arguments:" << endl << endl;
  cout << "ARGV ARRAY" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  { 
    cout << argv[i] << endl;
  }
  cout << endl << endl << "COPIED ARRAY" << endl;
  for(int i; i < numRows; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < argc; j++)
      {
        rArray[i][j] = argv[i][j];
      }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
    cout << "Copied array at index " << i << "is equal to " << rArray[i] << endl;;
  }
  cin.get();
}
```

The program outputs :

```
/a.out hello world
You have 3 arguments:

ARGV ARRAY
./a.out
hello
world


COPIED ARRAY
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why am I getting this error?  How do I fix it?

EDIT: I got a fix, changing the `char **rArray` to `string rArray`, and dynamically allocating the size from there.

Comment: `char** rArray` doesn’t allocate any memory for you, and `j < argc` isn’t the right condition.

Comment: @minitech Technically `char** rArray;` does allocate stack space (enough to hold a pointer).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Yeah, I took out “at all” because of that =P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `rArray` and also need to initialise the outer loop counter `i`.

Since the contents of `argv` are constant strings, you could just copy pointers to them

```
rArray = new char*[argc+1];
for(int i=0; i <= argc; i++) {
    rArray[i] = argv[i];
}
// use rArray
delete [] rArray;
```

Note that `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be `NULL`.  I've updated the loop to copy this as well (hence the unusual looking `i<=argc` exit condition)

If you really want to copy the content of the strings (as minitech suggests), the code becomes a bit more complicated:

```
rArray = new char*[argc+1];
for(int i=0; i < argc; i++) {
    int len = strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
    rArray[i] = new char[len];
    strcpy(rArray[i], argv[i]);
}
rArray[argc] = NULL;
// use rArray
for(int i=0; i < argc; i++) {
    delete [] rArray[i];
}
delete [] rArray;
```

Comment: This doesn’t copy the strings themselves, does it? I think that might have been the asker’s intent. Anyways, it’s `<`, not `<=`, right?

Comment: @minitech I've noted that the strings aren't (and needn't) be copied. `<=` is deliberate - I'll edit to explain why

Comment: Yes, `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be `NULL`, but `rArray[argc]` is also guaranteed to be out of bounds…

Comment: @minitech Thanks, that was daft!  I've hopefully corrected it now.

Comment: Shouldn't it be i< argc in the top code sample of this answer too?

Comment: @Michele See the text immediately after the first code sample.  `<=` is intentional to copy a pointer to the final argument passed (which happens to always be `NULL`)

Comment: When I try the copy content of strings example of this answer, it gives a Bad Ptr.

Comment: I'm using char** rArray.  Is that what you're using too @simonc ?

Comment: I got it working!  I started i at 1 and it caused the problem of it not entering the loop to copy the values into the new array.

Comment: Shouldn't `strlen(argv[i] + 1)` be `strlen(argv[i]) + 1`?

Comment: Rather old-school, wooden solution for a C++ question, though. See e.g. @FrerichRaabe's answer for a more idiomatic approach (unless you do need the nice, spartan resource-frugality of C in your particular case).

Answer (score 12):

Others pointed out various issues with your code; if you *actually* want to copy `argv`, use a `std::vector` of `std::string` objects:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    std::vector<std::string> args( argv, argv + argc );
}
```

Comment: +1 - a much better solution.  If you include a note about the crash-inducing problems with the current code, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @simonc, ahh, you meant "current code" in the _question_! OK, I've been desperately trying to find out how C++ is trying to kill us all again in the innocent-looking code of this _answer_ instead. :)

Answer (score 3):

One thing is that you are not initializing `i`

```
for(int i; i < numRows; i++)
        ^-- !
```

second thing is that `rArray` is not allocated

I suggest to use `std::vector<std::string>`, and copy all you arguments to vector, you will not need to worry about allocations/freeing memory.