# Transferring argv into a new array

Tags: c++, arrays

I can't figure out why this code is not working. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736069/copy-argv-into-new-array) but I still didn't get it. I get a segmentation fault (11) and do not see the `argv` array printed from the `testArray`.

My code so far

```c++
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    char testArray[argc];

    for (int i=0; argc; i++){
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
        testArray[i] = *argv[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; argc; i++){
        std::cout << testArray[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);` dont forget to `#include<string>`.

Comment: "New to C" but writting C++ (there is no `iostream` in C)? Note: C != C++

Comment: Hah sorry, mega newbie

Comment: But no variable length arrays in C++... What mysterious beast is this code?

Comment: Be aware that you only copy one character from each argument. That may not be intentional. Define an array of array of chars and look up strcpy.

Comment: Yes, I just realised, thanks

Comment: Let's not decide the language for OP's question, rather let's keep it intact and make him/her aware of the pro/cons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your code, change

```
  for (int i=0; argc; i++){
```

to

```
  for (int i=0; i < argc; i++){
```

Otherwise, there is *apparently* no conditional check for the `for` loop (`argc` will be `>= 1` and unchanged, usually), transforming it into an *infinite* loop.

FWIW, this unbound increment of `i` causes `testArray[i]` to access out-of-bound memory which causes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

That said, there is much more for you to be bothered. There is nothing called c and c++ code. They are very different and should be tread that way. Please do not mix them up. Each of them have their own advantages/disadvantages, use whichever suits you, but not both in a code.

Now, regarding the copying of array, `argv` is a pointer to the `argv[i]`s, which holds the command line arguments. `*argv[i]` does not give you the whole array at a time, it only points to the first element in the `argv[i]` array. So,

```
 testArray[i] = *argv[i];
```

does not copy the array. To copy it,

#### In C

1. You need to allocate a buffer of size `strlen(argv[i]) + 1`
2. use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)  to copy the `argv[i]` to the buffer.

#### In C++

You need to use [`std::copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/).

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is right, however, you have another mistake in your code. `char testArray[argc]` is not really an array of strings, but an array of chars (aka a string). So what you're doing here

```
testArray[i] = *argv[i];
```

is valid, but it only copies the first char of each argument to `testArray`. I don't think this is what you want.

To understand this, you must understand how pointers work.  `char** argv` is a double pointer. That means that it points to a list of `argc` pointers. So if you have two argument to your program, your argv will point to some place in memory where there is a list of three pointers. These three pointers each point to somewhere in memory where the respective argument is stored. To learn about pointers, the easiest way is to search youtube for `pointers c`.

So to copy them you should use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/).

Or you can copy only the pointer.

```
char* myArgv[argc];
myArgv[0]=argv[0];
myArgv[1]=argv[1];
//etc until argc
```

This works but you won't have copied the arguments themselves, just the pointers that point to them.